# ReactQuery - How to manipulate data on error

Tags: react-query

We work with a terrible API where a 404 response means an empty array.

Is there a way to tell React Query to convert 404 error to an empty array?

I am hoping there is a way to do something like this?

```js
const {data, isLoading, isError} = useQuery('key', apiCall, {
    onError: (error) => {
      if(error.statusCode === 404) {
        setData([]);
        setIsError(false);
      }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

react-query only cares about if your query function returns a resolved promise or a rejected promise. How you produce them is up to you. With that in mind, your query function can do more than just making an api call:

```
const {data, isLoading, isError} = useQuery(
  'key',
  async () => {
    try {
      return apiCall()
    } catch (error) {
      if(error.statusCode === 404) {
        return []
      }
      throw error
    }
  }
);
```

this will catch all errors, transforms 404 errors into a resolved promise and thus an empty `data` array, and re-throws all other errors so that they wind up in the `error` field.

This is potentially a lot better than doing transformations in `onError`, because with `onError`, all retries have already happened, so you might get multiple, unnecessary requests. Also, there might be an in-between render cycle where the error is actually rendered on the screen (depends on react batching really).

Answer (score 3):

You could do this

```
const queryClient = useQueryClient();
const emptyResponse = [];

const {data, isLoading, isError} = useQuery(key, apiCall, {
    onError: (error) => {
      if(error.statusCode === 404) {
        queryClient.setQueryData(key, emptyResponse);
      }
    }
});
```

This will overwrite you current cache in a query

Comment: Thanks! I have finally got it working and updated your answer accordingly. I also found that `setQueryData` does not only update `data` but also updates `error`,`isError`,`dataUpdatedAt` which is awesome!

Comment: Now that `onError` has been [deprecated](https://github.com/TanStack/query/discussions/5279), we should use TkDodo's approach